# What are these vertical lines of my negative?

Tags: film, developing

I've recently been home developing C-41 film with the tetenal colortec c-41 kit.

I use the Paterson reel tank and use the stick for agitation and a controlled water bath. My current theory is that it's uneven agitation and I'd be better with 30C developing or proper rotary development

I have checked and I can the lines of my negative, so I don't believe it's a scanner issue, so I'm left with a camera issue or a developing issue.

I'm using a hassleblad 500 c/m so I feel the leaf shutter wouldn't give the pattern I'm seeing?

Image attached

[image]

Comment: Definitely looks like uneven agitation.

Comment: I had something similar and it was a scanner issue. It happened for me when the scanner calibration drifted away. However, if you can see it on the negative, it may not be the case here.

Comment: Scanner calibration. Clean the scanner thoroughly and recalibrate.

Comment: Alex Barlow says: "I have checked and I can [see] the lines [on] my negative, so I don't believe it's a scanner issue, so I'm left with a camera issue or a developing issue" (my edits). If he can see the lines on the negative, it's not a scanner calibration issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are three plausible possibilities in general:

1. shutter problem with a focal-plane shutter;
2. scanning problem;
3. development problem, probably agitation;
4. light leak in the camera or around the edges of the roll, or keeping the roll somewhere there is very bright light.

From what you have said (1) and (2) can be ruled out: the camera has a leaf shutter, and the lines are on the neg.

I don't think it's (4) because the lines look too closely-spaced to me: whenever I've had light-related problems with 120 (due to the exposed roll seeing strong sunlight) it's been clear that light is getting in around the ends of the roll, and also through the backing paper in a broad band.  So I don't think it's this.

So I think it must be (3): agitation or some other processing issue.  And as you're processing it yourself & colour is fussy about agitation as it's designed for continuous agitation I think this is very plausible.  The glib answer is 'buy a Jobo', although they're terribly expensive (and the one I had was not electrically safe).

Answer (score 0):

I found the similar problem on my 135 color film.

[image]

I had 2 different rolls and they both have the same thing. And the lines are more obvious on underexposed images. I had them both developed at the same lab but on different days.I will use a different camera and test it again. For now, I'm sure that it is not the film or scanner's problem (the lab scan and my own scan show the same thing.)It could be my camera or the lab but since I see your photo, now I think it is highly likely the problem of processing.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED after re-reading the OP.  If you see it on the neg it is not the scanner.   Vertical lines indicate horizontal stress on the film.  Is your film advance lever moving smoothly or does it fight you a bit?   If your advance lever is smooth and there are no signs of stress on sprocket holes, it could be a light leak.  I don't think it's agitation.  Did you use enough chemical to cover your film?

Comment: Enough horizontal stress on film to cause vertical striations such as that would also be enough to tear sprocket holes.

Comment: Yes, it should be apparent in some way on the holes, too, but I have re-read the OP and made an edit.  Thank you for catching that.   He used a Hassy 500cm, though.

Answer (score -2):

I also faced these kind of things when using the scanner. This can be happened when the scanner calibration drifted away. Therefore you have to clean the scanner thoroughly and recalibrate with some technical supporter help.

To clean the scanner thoroughly and recalibrate, please refer the below link..

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHVjhk-F65Y